# Problem loading in bootstrap in localhost XAMPP

Tags: css, localhost

Hello I am working on a project on `XAMPP` localhost server. I am working on file in `E:/xampp/htdocs/main/admin/try.php` where I should link bootstrap CSS on `E:/xampp/htdocs/main/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

I have already tried using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="E:/xampp/htdocs/main/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />` but it did not work I also tried using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/main/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />` but none of them worked for me. Can anyone help me out. I don't want to use CDN.

Comment: What about using relative path instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in admin folder. You should move to main folder. Since admin and includes folders are in the same level then move to includes folder.

You can try

```
<link href="../includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try
`<link href="/main/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`